# ¿Por que me salta la excepción java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

La cosa es que el programa funciona bien, solo que en el do{ }while, la estoy liando un poquito, alguien sabria cual puede ser la causa del error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: esta hecho con programación modular, no he sacado captura de los métodos ya que he comprobado que funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Hola Igor, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El código de arriba funciona correctamente. Pide el nombre y lo pasa al método *buscoNombre*. Lo repite tantas veces como la respuesta sea *'s'*. No parece ser altamante funcional a nivel lógico. Pero la sintaxis es correcta y funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario Victor, aun soy estudiante y si a nivel lógico deduzco que no tendra mucho sentido simplemente son pruebas para ir asimilando conceptos, aun asi muchas graciass!!

Comment: Si he resuelto tu pregunta, agradecería que valoraras la respuesta indicándolo. Muchas gracias

Comment: *El código de arriba funciona correctamente* no lo sé. Quizás habra otro `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)` dentro del método `pideNombre` y lo mande a cerrar, cerrando así también la entrada para `System.in`

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade la información de los otros métodos y partes del programa. De esa forma podremos ayudarte a localizar el error

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, efectivamente user227 ha dado en el clavo, puse otro scanner en el primer metodo y me daba error por eso, XDDD.